# Using local library source

Tags: python, django, swagger

I feel like this is kind of a dumb question but I can't seem to find exactly how I should do this.

I am working on a django project, and am using [django-rest-swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) for documentation, however there are some (minor, but can not be done through existing configuration) modifications I'd like to make to django-rest-swagger so I've forked it and made some changes.

My question is this.... how do I get my django project to use my fork of django-rest-swagger(point it at my local source) rather than the one in /site-packages that was installed via pip? I would like to be able to make changes to my forked django-rest-framework and see it reflected in *my* Django projects docs.

I've Googled around but haven't found anything definitive... maybe I am just not Googling using the correct terminology.... or I'm really tired. Either way, any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks much!!

Comment: Why don't you install your modified version into `site-packages` (globally or in virtualenv)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `-e` flag, you can read about it [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs).

TLDR:

`pip install -e path/to/custom-swagger`

Although you might want to uninstall the version of swagger you have first so there's no namespace confusion

`pip uninstall django-rest-swagger`